# How to deserialize json string with indexed array

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have json file like this:

```
{
    "player": {
        "id": "29920",
        "name": "Random Name",
        "matches": {
            "0": {
                "position": "2",
                "points": "22.00"
            },
            "1": {
                "position": "2",
                "points": "22.00"
            },
            "2": {
                "position": "2",
                "points": "22.00"
            },
            "3": {
                "position": "2",
                "points": "22.00"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where amount of matches is quite big.
How to properly deserialized matches?

I have something like this:

```
public class PlayerInfo
{
    public player player;
}
public class player
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public List<matches> matches;
}
public class matches 
{
    public int position;
    public float points;
}
```

but matches are empty.

I call method:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerInfo>(json);
```

Comment: Yeah, your problem is `matches` is not an array so you gotta use dictionary semantics. Or fix your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The common way is to use a `Dictionary<string, Match>` Matches instead of `List<Match>`

```
Data data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

classes

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("player")]
    public Player Player { get; set; }
}

public partial class Player
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("matches")]
    public Dictionary<string, Match> Matches { get; set; }
}

public partial class Match
{
    [JsonProperty("position")]
    public long Position { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("points")]
    public string Points { get; set; }
}
```

if you need, you can still create a list instead of dictionary, but in this case your classes should be changed, you need to add an extra Num propery to Match

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("player")]
    public Player Player { get; set; }
}

public partial class Player
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("matches")]
    public List<Match> Matches { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Player(Dictionary<string, MatchDetail> matches)
    {
        Matches = matches.Select(m => new Match { Num = m.Key, MatchDetail = m.Value }).ToList();
    }

    public Player() {}
}
public partial class Match
{
    public string Num { get; set; }

    public MatchDetail MatchDetail { get; set; }
}

public partial class MatchDetail
{
    [JsonProperty("position")]
    public long Position { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("points")]
    public string Points { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but you should emphasize that the actual fix is changing the type of `Matches` from an array (list) to a dictionary.